# WCF Service Publishing and Fileless Activation : still create a .svc file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wcf-4

Using Visual Studio 2012, I have created a WCF 4.5 Service Library.
When the [service is published](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb924407%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to my local IIS, despite the [serviceActivations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/ee816902.aspx) section in the configuration file, a .svc file is still created.

I'm also using a custom factory in the configuration file, which, fortunately, isn't lost because serviceActivations overrides .svc files.

The configuration file look like this :

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
  <serviceActivations>
    <add factory="My.ServiceHostFactory" relativeAddress="~/BirtProxy.SoapReport.svc" service="BirtProxy.SoapReport" />
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

The .svc file that is created is like this :

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="BirtProxy.SoapReport" %>
```

I have several other services where I don't have this behavior, but I can't figure out what's wrong. I don't want this additional file to be created.

Any Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .svc file is created because the service isn't declared in the  configuration node. As soon as I've added the service, the file creation is gone.